# Creating Combinations from the array - Laravel Collect(crossJoin) Method

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to create Product Combinations from the response I am received through Form.

How do I pass the array items to the collect so that the combination is created

```php
      $newContent = array();
            foreach (array($request['varationsArray']) as $record) {
                $newContent[] = $record;
            }
    
            print_r($newContent);
   
       //Result
            // Array
            // (
            //     [0] => {"1":["Medium"],"2":["White","Blue"],"3":["Small","Large"]}
            // )
```

Learnt lately that Laravel has a built-in method - Collection [crossJoin()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-crossjoin) to accomplish it.

So I am expecting to save the combination to the database so that I could retrieve it late.

> Trying Collect for the result(newContent).

```php
     $variations = collect($newContent);
            $variations_options = $variations->crossJoin($newContent);
    
            print_r($variations_options->all());
    
            Array
       (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => {"1":["Medium"],"2":["White","Blue"]}
                [1] => {"1":["Medium"],"2":["White","Blue"]}
            )
    
       )
```

I am expecting the results to be saved in database like,

```
    product_combination 
    -------------------
    Medium-White
    Medium-Blue
    Medium
    Medium-White-Large
    ....
```

But I am unable to parse the above result.

Kindly brief me how to handle these type of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

you must read laravel documentation first. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-crossjoin

```
$collection = collect([1, 2]);

$matrix = $collection->crossJoin(['a', 'b']);

$matrix->all();

/*
    [
        [1, 'a'],
        [1, 'b'],
        [2, 'a'],
        [2, 'b'],
    ]
*/

$collection = collect([1, 2]);

$matrix = $collection->crossJoin(['a', 'b'], ['I', 'II']);

$matrix->all();

/*
    [
        [1, 'a', 'I'],
        [1, 'a', 'II'],
        [1, 'b', 'I'],
        [1, 'b', 'II'],
        [2, 'a', 'I'],
        [2, 'a', 'II'],
        [2, 'b', 'I'],
        [2, 'b', 'II'],
    ]
*/
```

at the end if you want to save it in database cocatenated by dash you can use this function :

```
implode('-',$crossJoinedArray)
```

Comment: I have updated my question with few more data.. How do I pass the array items to the collect so that the combination is created

Comment: can you explain more , im sorry but i am not getting what is your problem exactly.

Comment: I am trying to create combination from the above array. Since it has no static key, I am not able to pass those to the collect.